# Python scrollbar on text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get a simple scrollbar to show up on the text widget...I've derived the following code which adds the scrollbar but seems to eliminate the text widget completely.

```
eula = Tkinter.Text(screen1_2)
eula.insert("1.0", "text")
eula.pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
scroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(eula)
scroll.pack(side="right",fill="y",expand=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you must define `yscrollcommand=scroll.set` in the Text widget, and configure the scrollbar using the line: `scroll.config(command=eula.yview)`
Here is your code, rewritten with one scrollbar:

```
# Import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

# define master
master = Tk()

# Vertical (y) Scroll Bar
scroll = Scrollbar(master)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Text Widget
eula = Text(master, wrap=NONE, yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
eula.insert("1.0", "text")
eula.pack(side="left")

# Configure the scrollbars
scroll.config(command=eula.yview)
mainloop()
```

Here is a Tkinter example with two scrollbars:

```
# Import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

# define master
master = Tk()

# Horizontal (x) Scroll bar
xscrollbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# Vertical (y) Scroll Bar
yscrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Text Widget
text = Text(master, wrap=NONE,
            xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
            yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
text.pack()

# Configure the scrollbars
xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

# Run tkinter main loop
mainloop()
```

Comment: If all you need is a Text widget with a single vertical scrollbar, and you're not trying to solve this for academic reasons, I would recommend using ScrolledText. It is a Text widget with an integrated vertical scrollbar.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/scrolledtext.html for more details.